# Find DOM elements at top and bottom of scrolling div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll

I have a scrolling div containing list items. I have this boilerplate scroll event defined

```
$("#scrollingDiv").scroll(function(e) {

});
```

Inside of this scroll event function, how can I figure out which elements are at the top and bottom of the currently visible area?

Comment: Maybe you can iterate through the listed items checking if they are visible and create an array. then take the first and last ones. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling, You can use that as a function if you wanted, then iterate through your list and check each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try computing the positions of the list items with respect to the scrolling `<div>` and then scan the positions to see which ones match up with the `scrollTop` of the `<div>`.

Something like this perhaps:

```
var base = $('#scrollingDiv').offset().top;
var offs = [ ];
$('li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    offs.push({
        offset: $this.offset().top - base,
        height: $this.height()
    });
});
$("#scrollingDiv").scroll(function() {
    var y = this.scrollTop;
    for(var i = 0; i < offs.length; ++i) {
        if(y < offs[i].offset
        || y > offs[i].offset + offs[i].height)
            continue;
        // Entry i is at the top so do things to it.
        return;
    }
});
```

Live version (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yHH7C/

You'd probably want to play with the fuzziness of the `if` to get something that works sensibly (1px visible hardly makes an element the top one) but the basic idea should be clear enough. Mixing in the height of `#scrollingDiv` will let you see which `<li>` is at the bottom.

If you have a lot of list items, then a linear search might not be what you want but you should be able to solve that without too much effort.